# How do I create an Excel business spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, function, spreadsheet

Basically, I want to create a spreadsheet for my work which will show, Shop Names, Owner, Address, of an order was made, Type of Order (e.g. Online, Phone or In store), Date of last order, Paid, and Total Amount.

I am not good with Excel functions ect. so if someone could help that would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. The internet is full of Excel tutorials, get to work. 2. Your question is off-topic here, Excel questions belong on SuperUser. But it will get closed over there as well for lack of effort.

Comment: sorry but i'm no good on computers that is probably why there is a lack of effort. I don't have a clue what I am doing and I am running this alone

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to either manually create this or ideally to just import a CSV file (exported from an SQL service for example), which already has this format.

Comment: i should have mentioned before, we have a software that we use to take orders, which we would like to somehow link the spreadsheet to so that as soon as a certain company makes an order, it updates the spreadsheet. is that possible?

Comment: That is quite a different situation from what you write in your question. I suggest you take a breath, and write a *good* question containing all relevant info and post it on [SU]. Name the other software, ask for options.